# Enable template only for some std::vector<T2> type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I would to make a template match only for `T=std::vector<T2>` arguments (`T2` is an arbitrary type). I can use `boost::enable_if` in template arguments. How do I test whether a type `T` is a `std::vector`?

I could include `T::iterator` in my template so that non-container types would lead to substitution failure and would not be considered (SFINAE). This way though, any containers which define `T::iterator` would match, not only `std::vector<T2>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need `enable_if`, a simple partial specialization should be enough:

```
template <typename T>
struct Type { ... };

// partial specialization for std::vector
template <typename T>
struct Type< std::vector< T > > { ... };
```

If you are dealing with a function template, you can simply provide an overload:

```
template <typename T>
void foo( const T & t ) { ... }

// overload for std::vector
template <typename T>
void foo( const std::vector< T > & vec ) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 That makes a lot of sense. I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought T2 was some fixed type.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure if the overload for std::vector would be preferred.

Comment: I had to use dots because the compiler complained of a lack of parameters. https://ideone.com/UBPVL6  // overload for std::vector
template <class...T>
int foo( const std::vector< T ... > & vec ) { return 2; }

Comment: @QuentinUK not sure what you mean, it works ok with a single template argument: https://ideone.com/95FuVU

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
template <class T2>
struct is_std_vector { static const bool value=false; };

template <class T2>
struct is_std_vector<std::vector<T2> > { static const bool value=true; };
```

Use together with `enable_if`!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even want to use a template for that? Can't you just write a plain function?

Anyhow, it's possible:

```
template<class T
  ,class=typename std::enable_if<(
    std::is_same<T,std::vector<int>>::value
  )>::type
>
void foo(T const& vec)
```

(this is C++11: default template arguments for function templates + type_traits + >> not being a shift operator)

Edit: I just realized that T2 in your question is probably not some fixed type but a placeholder to allow many kinds of vectors. In that case, I recommend accepting Luc's answer.

Viele Grüße nach Österreich! :-)